# Движение к движущемуся объекту. Эффект самонаведения

Tags: ios, разработка-игр, swift, spritekit

Мне нужно реализовать эффект самонаведения. Есть движущийся Объект А, к нему должен подлетать другой Объект Б.

Сейчас я в методе `update`, каждый кадр пересчитываю координаты Объекта А на сцене. Как сделать так, что бы Объект Б летел к Объекту А?

`SKAction.moveTo` не подходит, т.к. за время подлета, Объект А успевает переместиться в другое место (получается что Объекта Б летит к той позиции, в которой Объект А находился в момент создания этого `SKAction`).

Comment: По какой траектории движется Объект А, прямолинейно, с ускорением, меняются ли это со временем ?

Answer (score 1):

На Habrahabr полгода назад была отличная статья "[Методы наведения летательных аппаратов в разработке игр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/254485/)"

Так же гуглите по терминам "Алгоритм преследования" и "Pursuit algorithm"

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).